# Kubeflow Pipelines error on GCP - Run doesn't end

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pipeline, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

After submitting the "run" using Jupyter notebook, when I go to the Kubeflow pipeline dashboard, I can see my "run" submitted & running but it doesn't end even after few hours & doesn't show any logs either.

I have tried running the "DEMO XG-BOOST" but the same issue persists & the "run" doesn't end.

Can someone please help me understand if there is any issue with the account settings or any other issue which I'm missing because I have tried to check documentation & other websites but couldn't understand why this occurs.

Please note that this "run" was working fine (creating the pipeline flow) on coursera using quicklabs (Covertype classifier)

[error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SycjI.png)

Using below versions:
kfp 1.8.12 ;
kfp-pipeline-spec 0.1.14;
kfp-server-api 1.8.1;
Python 3.7.12

If there is any other information which I have missed to put above, please let me know so I could share that information that could help us solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue mentioned above has been resolved. The part where "DEMO XG-BOOST" run doesn't end has been resolved by selecting "Use emissary executor" option while creating the pipeline.

[see the snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77j3P.png)

When we launch the pipeline with this setting, it solved the issue & we can run complete pipelines now.

**More details:**
We took support from GCP & they have mentioned that the issue might have been caused by a recent upgrade of the GKE cluster which removes the docker runtime (https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/installation/choose-executor/#docker-executor). Namely, the Docker executor is the default workflow executor and depends on docker container runtime, which is deprecated on Kubernetes 1.20+. We were using a GKE cluster whose version was 1.21.6. Hence the issue. So, we used the documentation (https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/installation/choose-executor/#migrate-to-emissary-executor) & migrated to the Emissary executor (instead of Docker) which has solved our issue.